# How to disable Ctrl+Enter full screen toggle in AWS Amazon Workspace function?

Tags: amazon-workspaces

I recently learned that pressing Ctrl+Alt+Enter while in an AWS workspace will toggle full screen mode. I tried that and it worked. But now when I press Ctrl+Enter it too toggles full screen mode which I do not want. Ctrl+Enter is a very common and unique function for my job that it's hard for me to remember not to use it and even if I do the alternative involves additional steps/time. Is there any way I can disable the Ctrl+Enter key binding for AWS workspace?

Comment: This is a bugbear of mine rn. Ctrl+Enter is a shortcut for running a chunk of code in Snowflake and/or Databricks. But it is also the shortcut for toggling view setting is AWS Workspace. I don't have control over the AWS environment so I don't know how to fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workspace restarted itself later in the week. I suspect for a Windows update. The restart or the update fixed the issue.